# How to set localization to UITabBarController?

Tags: swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I Have a UITabBarController with two ViewControllers (VC). The App has two Localizable.strings files (English and German). The tab bar items are custom icons. Both VCs are embedded in Navigation Controllers (NC). The titles are set in the NCs in the Bar Item -> Title section of the storyboard.

In addition I put this line of code into the ViewDidLoad of the second VC:

```
self.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString("Item 2", comment: "")
```

When the APP starts (and the first VC is called), the title of it's tab bar icon is being translated. But the second tab bar icon title will only be translated when it is tapped.

How can I get the second tab bar icon translated at start? Do I have to do it in the AppDelegate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:
I added the following awakeFromNib method:

```
    override  func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.title = NSLocalizedString("Item 2", comment: "")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 - You should not add the wakeFromNib method. Localize the Main.storyboard and add your translation there.